# Recovering ubuntu from graphics card crash

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

I have a dual boot system (XP/Ubuntu) and have had a graphics card crash on me. I have installed a new graphics card (after the first one stopped responding) and I am able to boot into windows no problem. The new card is a Gigabyte ATI Radeon 4650 HD. I did install an ATI catalist control center in Ubuntu under the old card but Ubuntu complained I did not have any ATI products installed so I think I uninstalled it (I was about to start installing drivers when the old card crashed).

When I currently try to boot Ubuntu the moniter is black except the top 1cm that is garbled pixcles. This is the same problem that I had with the old card but the old card stopped displaying the POST or windows so I believed it was the card and not both OS's.

I have tried using recovery mode to fix broken packages, graphics and the file system. I have also tried to use the installed version of Ubuntu (ie not the latest upgraded version) and still the same problem.

The last thing I have tried is booting from the live CD and that loads with no graphics problems.

How do I get Ubuntu to realise I have a new graphics card and use it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing a search for any packages with fglrx i them and using apt-get -purge on them. That allowed me to boot into Ubuntu but now I have to figure out how to update my drivers without it crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: you should boot to the recovery mode (not LiveCD if possible) and run this from there.

Comment: Tried this and was able to reconfigure the settings but did not fix the problem.