# Lost graphical boot after an upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-9.04

Luckily I have attempted it in a `VMWare` environment, and have taken a snapshot right before the upgrade. In addition, my `FreeNX` connection that used to work now would not (probably same cause).

I am able to log in on the console, when I hit `Ctrl - Alt - F1`.
However, I am no Linux pro, and I am not sure which log file(s) to start with, or what to try.

Would you kindly walk me though this? I will post my steps as I go.

Hardware: http://archive.slickdeals.net/showthread.php?t=1212747

```
$uname - a
Linux [name] 2.6.28-19-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 18:00:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: me too.  i think it's because i am using closed source drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the same/very similar question resolved:

[No GUI after upgrade to Ubuntu 9.10 (boots to command line)](https://superuser.com/questions/63759/no-gui-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-9-10-boots-to-command-line)

Good luck.

[EDIT]: If this doesn't resolve your problem, attempt to replace your xorg.conf from /etc/X11 with one of the standard configurations. Then, once you've restart the x11 server, you can attempt to re-install your graphics drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by examining X.org log files, located at `/var/log/X.0.log`.

Try reconfiguring X server.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reinstall xorg :

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Then follow by Sathya's suggestion to reconfigure xorg:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

or

```
sudo xorgconfig
```

If that doesn't help, you might check if [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) was correctly installed by the 9.10 upgrade.
From [How To Check Installed GRUB Version Number](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Bash%20Commands.html#GRUB_Version_Number) :

```
grub-install -v
```

Comment: It boots into non-graphic mode. Why would Grub2 affect anything? How can I check that Grub2 was installed correctly?

Comment: I have added the check. Ubuntu 9.10 comes with Grub2, so if the upgrade had a problem you might not have it.

Comment: Cool, the first command led me to: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=388348

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me: http://mikebeach.org/2010/06/nvidia-proprietary-drivers-and-low-resolution-plymouth-splash-screen/ it doesn't perform perfectly and without glitches on shutdown every time, but you ALWAYS get the boot graphic

Comment: all the fancypants visual effects still load for compiz and video doesn't get choppy, so I'm satisfied